# Password manager with revision control

Tags: linux, open-source, version-control, password-manager

I would like to use a password manager that creates revisions for every (saved) change.

I don’t want to build something myself (e.g., using text files), so it should be a dedicated application (but it’s fine if the application uses tools like Git and GnuPG, as long as I don’t have to set them up or manually invoke them).
I don’t mind if it’s text-based or if it has a GUI.

Currently I’m using [Revelation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revelation_%28software%29), but it lacks the revision feature.

These revisions should be

- per entry or per field, not a full revision of *all* entries
- created automatically, ideally after each manual save
- browsable, ideally with a (graphical) diff
- saved forever, ideally also for deleted entries
- saved encrypted, ideally in the same file/database as the current data

The password manager should

- save the sensitive data encrypted
- offer at least fields for URL, username and password, but ideally allow to add custom fields
- let me list all entries
- offer a search/filter function, ideally searching over all fields, and optionally only in specific fields
- let me export all my data (ideally including revisions) in some common format

A solution must be a **FLOSS** and run natively on **GNU/Linux**.

Comment: What are your requirements on the password manager aspect? Going strictly by your description, a bunch of text files (one per entry) on an encrypted volume stored under any version control system would do.

Comment: @Gilles: Right, thanks -- I’ve updated the question.

Answer (score 4):

[**KeePass 2**](http://keepass.info/download.html) has a [history](http://keepass.info/help/v2/entry.html#history) for every entry (automatically updated).

It runs on Linux, however I think it was ported from Windows, and the Linux version looks a little ugly.

I think it does everything else you list except showing a diff between revisions.